# Optimize MySQL query with many joins and filters

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

I'm having a MySQL query that count number of emails that passes certain filters (time filter and free search)

The query is currently taking at least 30 seconds on my server (time interval of only 12 days) and so I want to make it more efficient.

I don't have lot of experience with MySQL so please be gentle with me.

The current query is:

```
SELECT
count(distinct emls.EML_ID) as count FROM origins
JOIN emls ON emls.EML_ID = origins.source_id
JOIN email2addresses ON emls.EML_ID = email2addresses.EML_ID
JOIN email_addresses ON email_addresses.Email_ID = email2addresses.Email_ID
JOIN files ON files.Origin_ID = origins.Origin_ID
JOIN unique_files ON unique_files.Unique_File_ID = files.Unique_File_ID
WHERE origins.insert_date BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1533323333) and FROM_UNIXTIME(1534323333)
and (origins.source_id LIKE "%%" or emls.Subject LIKE "%%"
or email_addresses.Email_Address LIKE "%%" or files.File_Name LIKE "%%"
or files.File_ID LIKE "%%" or unique_files.File_Hash LIKE "%%");
```

When running `explain` before the query I get:

```
    1   SIMPLE  origins             index   PRIMARY,Source_ID_index Source_ID_index 5       10699008    11.11   Using where; Using index
    1   SIMPLE  emls                eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   origins.Source_ID   1   100.00  
    1   SIMPLE  files               ref Unique_File_ID_index,Origin_ID_index    Origin_ID_index 5   origins.Origin_ID   1   100.00  Using where
    1   SIMPLE  unique_files        ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   files.Unique_File_ID    1   100.00  
    1   SIMPLE  email2addresses     ref EML_ID_index,Email_ID_index EML_ID_index    5   origins.Source_ID   4   100.00  Using where
    1   SIMPLE  email_addresses     eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   email2addresses.Email_ID    1   100.00  Using where
```

What I'm doing in the query is basically building a huge table (many joins) and then applying the filters on that huge table, I believe it's really bad practice.

To be more specific, the questions are:

1. How can I rewrite this query so that 
   at first,  time filter is applied to the `origins` table and only after, all the joins take effect on the partial `origins` table (only on the records that matches time filter)?
2. On the first row at the `explain` output, I get under `row` the value `10699008` , that is the expected amount of records that MySQL will need to go through, right? If I understand correctly that I should try and lower it in order to gain speed, is there a best practice regarding how to do this?
3. Are there any other improvements I should apply to this query to make it faster?

Thanks.

Comment: As well as the EXPLAIN, questions about query performance ALWAYS require CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables. However, I will observe that "%%" is an odd parameter.

Comment: @Strawberry , no, and I don't think I do it, I query for result between dates AND like '%%' . The '%%' is just a wild cards added around the search value, in the example I gave, there's no search value so putting '%%' will query everything (no free search filter applied).